# How to create items for ArrayList based on user input

Tags: java

I'm making an inventory program for my class. I have an Item class, Inventory class with an ArrayList, and an Inventory tester class. I want to ask the user how many items they want to add to inventory and then add those items based on their parameters. This is what I have but it isn't working:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InventoryTester
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Inventory myInventory = new Inventory();

    System.out.println("Enter 1 to print all inventory data");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 to add items to the inventory");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 to ");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 to ");
    int choice = input.nextInt();

    if (choice == 1)
    {
      myInventory.printAllData();
    }

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
      System.out.println("How many items are you adding?");
      int numOfItemsToAdd = input.nextInt();


      for (int i = 0; i < numOfItemsToAdd; i++)
      {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of item " + i);
        input.nextLine();
        String tempName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the type of item " + i);
        String tempType = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the price of item " + i);
        double tempPrice = input.nextInt();

        Item newItem = new Item(tempName, tempType, tempPrice);
        myInventory.addItem(newItem);
      }
    }
    input.close();
  }
}
```

EDIT: What I thought my problem was, wasn't actually my problem. I got this piece working.

Comment: I see no list...

Comment: Everytime you use .nextInt(), the function collects user input. So you should only use input.nextInt() once and then store that value in a variable. And then check if the value of the variable is 1 or 2 (to print all or add items respectively)

Comment: I just changed it a little

Comment: You've only shown the irrelevant code. We need to see your `Inventory` class and its `addItem` method, where your `List` lives presumably. Voting to close this Question as unclear. I suggest you delete this Question before it collects down-votes, read the Java Tutorial by Oracle, and search for the many existing ArrayList questions already asked and answered on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nextInt() and nextLine() together, you need to consume the last new line character before calling nextLine(). So you need to add an extra .nextLine() before your for loop like so:

```
int numOfItemsToAdd = input.nextInt();

input.nextLine(); //ADDED CODE

  for (int i = 0; i <= numOfItemsToAdd; i++)
  {
    System.out.println("Enter the name of item " + i + 1);
    String tempName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the type of item " + i + 1);
    String tempType = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the price of item " + i + 1);
    double tempPrice = input.nextInt();

    Item newItem = new Item(tempName, tempType, tempPrice);

    myInventory.addItem(newItem);
  }
```